How to filter a table using linq?
I have data table like below



Metal
value




silver
5


silver_ref
Y


gold
2


gold_ref
N


iron
N


iron_ref
N



From this data table I want to filter like below way
if silver,gold,iron != 'N' and silver_ref,gold_ref,iron_ref = 'Y'. So data table will become



Id
value




silver
5



How can I achieve using linq

Can you show POCO class for this table?

I am getting this as DataTable,and want to modify with 2nd Data Table format

Your data design is far from ideal, but we can work with what you've got.
One way to get your desired results would be to self-join the table with itself, matching up the non-"_ref" rows with the "_ref" rows. A where clause could then filter out the results that don't pass the remaining requirements.
The result would be something like:
var results =
    from d1 in data
    join d2 in data on (d1.Metal + "_ref") equals d2.Metal
    where d1.value != "N" && d2.value == "Y"
    select d1;

See this .NET Fiddle.
The above is not specifically limited to "gold", "silver", and "iron" metals.

could not find the implemention of the query pattern for source type Data Table join not found getting the error

Well, for LINQ to work, the data sources need to be an IEnumerable<> or IQueryable<> of some type. What is the datatype of data in your code? (Unrelated: I updated the answer above to swap the expressions in the on ... equals ....)
